# Flutter SSO (Single Sign On) using **windows ADFS**

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, adfs

I want to add authentication with SSO (Single Sign On) using **windows ADFS** in flutter app.

But I didn't find any helpful doc or package for integration with flutter.

So any suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: Hi @AdnanKhan. Did you find any solution to implement SSO in Flutter app?

Comment: I am using this logic but no luck. Waiting for response. 
https://github.com/teranetsrl/oauth2_client/issues/161